# display 4 months in a full Calendar

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar

I am using full Calendar plugin in my project. I want to display contiously 4 months. Please look at the below image,

[image]

I want to display 4 months in a full calendar. Please Help me how can I do this?

Already I have an js file, it will display 3 months simultaniously. But I want 4 months calendar. Please look at the below link which has having 3 months,

https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=2236

In this link, **fullcalendar-cc.js** file is there. It will display 3 months.

Please help me how can I display 4 month ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a custom view and adding in views:

```
views: {
    agendaToDisplayFourWeek: {
        type: 'timeline',
        slotLabelFormat: 'ddd D', // Mon 3 etc
        slotDuration: '24:00', // slots per day? 12:00 i.e. 12 hours AM/PM
        duration: { weeks: 4 }
    }
}
```